# Migrating classic asp web site to IIS 10 from IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, iis-10

I am trying to migrate a classic asp web site to IIS 10 from IIS 6.0. My handler mapping looks like below. I want to add classic asp in handler mapping, but don't know what to select for the types drop down. In the older version of IIS, I don't have type drop down, I only have executable where I typed

```
 %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
```

Also, do I need to add anything else like aspq-ISAPI-4.0_64bit in HTTP handlers in order for my classic asp web site to work. My web site is giving an error " 404 - File or directory not found.". This web site is working perfectly on IIS 6.0

[image]

Comment: You haven't mentioned if you have installed the ASP module or anything. It would probably be best to search Google for "iis 10 classic asp" and find instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As andrew say's you should make sure you have installed the asp module for your IIS. More details about how to install the classic asp in the window10 or windows server, you could refer to below steps:

1.Install the classic asp in the windows server:

1.On the taskbar, click Server Manager.

2.In Server Manager, click the Manage menu, and then click Add Roles and Features.

3.In the Add Roles and Features wizard, click Next. Select the installation type and click Next. Select the destination server and click Next.

4.On the Server Roles page, expand Web Server (IIS), expand Web Server, and then expand Application Development.

5.On the Server Roles page, select ASP.

6.If the Add features that are required by ASP? dialog box appears, click Add Features. (This page appears only if you have not already installed ISAPI Extensions on your server.)

7.On the Server Roles page, ASP and ISAPI Extensions should be selected. Click Next.

8.Then you could click the next and install to complete the installing

For the windows 10 application:

1.On the Start screen, move the pointer all the way to the lower left corner, right-click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.

2.In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.

3.Expand Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, expand Application Development Features, and then select ASP.

4.Click OK to wait for installing.

Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis).